# Service Discovery Fail - Bluetooth Chat Connection using SPP

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, serial-port

So I have compiled and succesfully ran the Android Bluetooth Chat project on eclipse (API8).

The issue is, when I connect to my own embedded Bluetooth Device (http://www.sparkfun.com/products/582) It says "Service Discovery Fail" in debug mode.

I searched, and found this post: [Service discovery failed exception using Bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/android-bluetooth-service-discovery-failed-exception)

How every I get a compilation error.

I have several quick fixes in eclipse. None of which work. I am new to java.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the only absolutely essential modification to make to the Bluetooth Chat application to enable connection to the SPP profile of a Bluetooth device is to use the SPP UUID. Change MY_UUID as follows:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

With this UUID I find I am able to connect to a large range of SPP Bluetooth modules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Something interesting happened after changing the UUID. I can now sometime connect via debug mode if I go step by step (breakpoint at Connection point) However, still the same issue.

Comment: This solved my problem.+1. Tried to connect any Android 2.2+ phone to Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.