# Android Bluetooth Connecting Error

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

Im getting the follow messages in my stack trace. I can find Bluetooth Devices, but when I try to open the socket this happens.

```
10-30 22:23:08.901: ERROR/BTL_CFG(8633): WARNING : [service.brcm.bt.INQ_FILTER_BDA] property_get failed (0)
10-30 22:23:24.585: ERROR/BTLD(8633): ****************search UUID = 1454***********
10-30 22:23:24.600: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(2502): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Device already exists)
10-30 22:23:24.616: ERROR/DTUN_HCID4(8659): No device pointer found for peer! Ignore Error = true. Ignoring error...
10-30 22:23:26.093: ERROR/DTUN_HCID4(8659): discovery unsuccessful!
10-30 22:23:30.628: ERROR/CachedBluetoothDevice(18609): onUuidChanged: Time since last connect 1440232. mInitiatedPairing: false
10-30 22:23:30.632: ERROR/CachedBluetoothDevice(18609): onUuidChanged: Time since last connect1440236.mInitiatedPairing:false
```

**EDIT:**

The socket attempts to open but doesnt, an exception is thrown `(Service Discovery failed)` and then the socket is closed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer and it remedies it

[Service discovery failed exception using Bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/android-bluetooth-service-discovery-failed-exception)

Just wish I knew what was actually happening :(