# Android to Nokia data transfer via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, nokia

I am trying to connect my Android phone to my Nokia phone. I can discover the Nokia phone through my Andorid application. I can create the socket successfully:

```
btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

But when I try to connect to the nokia phone there is an error in connection.
I am trying to run this sample provided in the link below:

http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/serial-over-bluetooth-simple-test-client-t11106.html

And an error is occured when the code `btSocket.connect()` which is present in the `onResume()` method is executed:

#### Logcat:

```
D/BluetoothAdapter(  176): checkBluetoothAddress
E/THINBTCLIENT( 4738): ON RESUME: Exception during connect.
E/THINBTCLIENT( 4738): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
E/THINBTCLIENT( 4738):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:377) 
E/THINBTCLIENT( 4738):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:201)<br>
E/THINBTCLIENT( 4738):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
```

And this is the `UUID` I am using:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong. I tried to look for help in Stackoverflow and on the internet in general, but no help was found.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? Am facing this now.

Comment: No dude. I have kept that on hold now.

Comment: It might help to know what kind of Nokia phone you're trying to connect to.

Comment: I am trying to connect Nokia E63 running on Symbian to Samsung Pop running on Android

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution found here: [Service discovery failed exception using Bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android)

For some reason unclear to me, reflection works on some devices where the ordinary method doesn't work. Try this:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class} );
btSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```