# determining BluetoothServerSocket channel

Tags: android, bluetooth

I registered a service via

```
BluetoothServerSocket bs = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("someName" , UUID.fromString(myUuid)  );
```

My question is, is there any programmatic way to determine which channel is being used by this service?

============================ANOTHER SOLUTION========================
:
Thanks for your anserw @Skaard-Solo ,but if I use reflection to create socket then i cannot provide uuid for this. 
I made some research and I wrote some simple function that can obtain channel from BluetoothServerSocket.

```
public int getChannel(BluetoothServerSocket bsSocket){
    Field[] f = bsSocket.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    int channel = -1;

    for (Field field : f) {
        if(field.getName().equals("mChannel")){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                channel = field.getInt(bsSocket);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            field.setAccessible(false);
        }
    }

    return channel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (AFAIK), and that's can be a problem. Android choose a channel which is free during the socket openning.

If you really need to know the channel, you can create a rfcomm socket by reflection, and passing the channel as parameter (Kind of a hack, `listenUsingRfcommOn` is @hide in Android) :

```
BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
Method m;
m = mAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(mAdapter, BLUETOOTH_CHANNEL);
```

[Check also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818800/should-i-leave-the-bluetooth-reflection-hack-in-production-code), which deals with this ;)