# Can only restablish a bluetooth connection a finite number of times

Tags: bluetooth

I have an application (activity and service) which can establish a connection with a separate device and pull data off it over spp Bluetooth.

It need to do this once a day.

However, there appears to be a limit to the number of times that phone (server) can reestablish a connection with the device (client).

In the LogCat, I see this error:
BluetoothEventLoop.ccp

onCreateDeviceResult: D.Bus error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded (The maximum number of pending replies per connection has been reached)

BluetoothEventLoop Result of onCreateDeviceResult:-1

I'm thinking about programmatically rebooting the phone but would rather not have to do this?

Have you any ideas how to overcome this problem.

Ideally, the phone will be running as a hub, permanently connected to a power supply, for many weeks.
I'm running Android 2.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this method to create the socket in your connect thread?

```
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

I had the same error on 2.3.6 and fixed it using the reflection method. I replaced the above code with:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

I used the same solution as this other problem:
[Service discovery failed exception using Bluetooth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android)