# Bluetooth Pair between Glass and Computer Fails

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, android-bluetooth

I am attempting to send messages between Glass and my computer using bluetooth.  Background info on the computer

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Name: ubuntu-0

MAC of bluetooth: 60:D8:19:AC:61:15

After running my code (see this thread for the actual code [Android Bluetooth Client and Server Won't Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866100/android-bluetooth-client-and-server-wont-connect)) I get a screen that shows a picture of a generic phone on the left, and to the right says ubuntu-o Pair? Tap if displaying "768914"

My computer is not displaying those numbers, but I know that is the correct device, so I tap and the screen changes to show a Pairing screen.  After a while it says pairing failed.  Here is the log:

> 02-26 11:27:51.746: D/CONNECTTEST(1895): Try to open socket 02-26
>   11:27:52.488: I/PowerManagerService(198): Auto-brightness: light
>   sensor = 164, brightness = 255 mHighestLightSensorValue: 8485 02-26
>   11:27:54.816: I/PowerManagerService(198): Auto-brightness: light
>   sensor = 224, brightness = 255 mHighestLightSensorValue: 8485 02-26
>   11:27:55.683: D/PowerManagerService(198): setTimeoutLocked now=2497220
>   when=2503220 currentTimeoutOverride=-1 nextTimeoutOverride=-1
>   currentState=3 nextState=1 02-26 11:27:56.543: D/OpenGLRenderer(373):
>   Flushing caches (mode 0) 02-26 11:27:56.683: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:conn_complete() status 0x00
>   02-26 11:27:56.683: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/adapter.c:adapter_get_device()
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.683: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/adapter.c:adapter_create_device()
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.683: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:device_create() Creating device
>   /org/bluez/817/hci0/dev_60_D8_19_AC_61_15 02-26 11:27:56.683:
>   V/bluez(817): external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:btd_device_ref()
>   0x1dc1cd8: ref=1 02-26 11:27:56.683: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:device_set_temporary() temporary
>   1 02-26 11:27:56.691: D/BluetoothEventLoop(198): Property Changed:
>   Devices : 3 02-26 11:27:56.707: D/BluetoothEventLoop(198): Device
>   property changed: 60:D8:19:AC:61:15 property: Connected value: true
>   02-26 11:27:56.715: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:remote_features_information()
>   hci0 status 0 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:remote_name_information()
>   hci0 status 0 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:link_key_request() hci0 dba
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:get_auth_info() hci0 dba
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:link_key_request() kernel
>   auth requirements = 0x05 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:link_key_request() Matching
>   key not found 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:io_capa_request() hci0 IO
>   capability request for 60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.723:
>   V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:get_auth_info() hci0 dba
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:get_io_cap() initial
>   authentication requirement is 0x05 02-26 11:27:56.723: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:get_io_cap() loc_auth=0x5
>   loc_cap=0x1 rem_auth=0xFF rem_cap=0x0 02-26 11:27:56.723:
>   V/bluez(817): external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:get_io_cap()
>   final authentication requirement is 0x05 02-26 11:27:56.941:
>   V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:io_capa_response() hci0 IO
>   capability response from 60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:57.137:
>   I/PowerManagerService(198): Auto-brightness: light sensor = 182,
>   brightness = 255 mHighestLightSensorValue: 8485 02-26 11:27:57.277:
>   V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/plugins/hciops.c:user_confirm_request() hci0
>   02-26 11:27:57.277: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/adapter.c:adapter_get_device()
>   60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26 11:27:57.277: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/device.c:device_request_authentication()
>   Requesting agent authentication for 60:D8:19:AC:61:15 02-26
>   11:27:57.277: V/bluez(817):
>   external/bluetooth/bluez/src/agent.c:agent_request_confirmation()
>   Calling Agent.RequestConfirmation: name=:1.0,
>   path=/android/bluetooth/agent, passkey=050032 02-26 11:27:57.277:
>   I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(198): agent_event_filter: Received method
>   org.bluez.Agent:RequestConfirmation 02-26 11:27:57.277:
>   D/BluetoothBondState(198): setBondState address: 60:D8:19:AC:61:15
>   state: 11reason: 0 02-26 11:27:57.277: E/BluetoothHeadset(198): Could
>   not bind to Bluetooth Headset Service 02-26 11:27:57.277:
>   E/BluetoothBondState(198): Proxy is
>   null:android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp@418299f0:null 02-26 11:27:57.277:
>   D/BluetoothBondState(198): 60:D8:19:AC:61:15 bond state 10 -> 11 (0)
>   02-26 11:27:57.277: W/ActivityManager(198): Unable to start service
>   Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothHeadset }: not found 02-26
>   11:27:57.285: I/PairingPolicy/pairingReceiver(373):
>   ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED: ubuntu-0 @ [60:D8:19:AC:61:15] BONDING

Can anyone tell me why the pair is failing?  Should I be worried that the Pair screen shows a picture of a phone? Will Glass not allow apps to communicate with devices other that phones on Bluetooth?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't know the answer in your case, but I do know that Glass pairs with my Surface Pro (Win 8.1) just fine. It does show a phone on the paring screen on Glass; however, Win 8.1 also shows a corresponding pairing acknowledgement dialog with the numbers which it seems isn't showing up in your case on your Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the computer to pair with Glass using this: http://www.glassappsource.com/listing/bluetooth-manager-glass