# Bluetooth connection failed android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am getting bluetooth connection failed error when try to connect.

```
    Logs

    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): initSocketNative
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): ...fd 53 created (RFCOMM, lm = 0)
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): initSocketFromFdNative
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): connectNative
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): ...connect(53, RFCOMM) = -1 (errno 16)
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): abortNative
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): ...asocket_abort(53) complete
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): destroyNative
    BluetoothSocket.cpp(8398): ...asocket_destroy(53) complete
```

Let me know where I am doing wrong.

My code snippet:

```
    mmSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    mmSocket.connect();
```

Comment: check this SO Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android

Comment: Hi, I tried but not getting success. I am facing the problem in micromax. Any solution?