# What is onBluetoothServiceDown error?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm getting the following error while continuously scanning for ble devices on android.

> onBluetoothServiceDown: Sending callbacks to 1 clients
>   onBluetoothServiceDown: Finished sending callbacks to registered clients

The Bluetooth switches of immediately.

Comment: This probably happens when If Bluetooth is off,Maximum name/address remote retrieval retry exceeded,Bluetooth service disconnected

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/59c53c6/services/java/com/android/server/BluetoothManagerService.java

Comment: Look at this answer, I hope it's useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397739/6534576