# Xamarin bluetooth in Android connection fails

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.droid

I'm trying to establish a bluetoothconnection to another phoner. Later on, it'll be a board with a HC5 module, but for debugging I'm just using a phone.

The problem is, that connect fails and throws an IO Exception: 
" read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

A quick google-search shows a lot having this problem. The only way I can see it solved, is by using a method not public in the API

```
Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);
```

The problem just is, that `createRfcommSocket` has been removed, and the result from getMethod will be null.

My code is from the example: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat which for connecting is:

```
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothChatService service)
        {
            UUID MY_UUID = UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            mmDevice = device;
            _service = service;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try
            {
                if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 10) // Gingerbread 2.3.3 2.3.4
                    tmp = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                else
                    tmp = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);


            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
```

Since the 'original hack' doesn't work, and I haven't found any other solution, I'm hoping somebody here knows how to fix this.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue I and others in my company have come across when working with Bluetooth devices from Android phones. It is well described on SO here: [Service Discovery Failed Exception Using Bluetooth On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397071/service-discovery-failed-exception-using-bluetooth-on-android)

The method you describe as being removed is, in fact, still operational. And it is the one we have successfully used. We attempt connection using the

```
tmp = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

method you show above.
Use a try...catch block around tmp.Connect()  (your code does not show the Connect call)
In the catch block "re-create" the BluetoothSocket using the createRfcommSocket method. I used a small method to do this:

```
       private BluetoothSocket CreateRfcommSocket(BluetoothDevice bTdevice)
    { // This is an "undocumented" call that is needed to (mostly) avoid a Bluetooth Connection error
      // introduced in Android v4.2 and higher. It is used as a "fallback" connection.
      // Full paths version of code!
      //Java.Lang.Reflect.Method mi = device.Class.GetMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Java.Lang.Class[] { Java.Lang.Integer.Type });
      //_bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket)mi.Invoke(device, 1);

        // Compact version of above
        var mi = bTdevice.Class.GetMethod("createRfcommSocket", Integer.Type);
        return (BluetoothSocket)mi.Invoke(bTdevice, 1);
    }
```

This is the method indicated here: [Xamarin Forum Post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103257/bluetooth-device-error-java-io-ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-or-timeout)

I have tested this on Android 4.4.2 and Android 8.0 and it works on these systems. Another person in the company has tested the Java equivalent code on Android: 4.2.2, 4.4.2, 7.0 and 8.0 and it works in every case.